# Remainder term for the expansion of $\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}$

Tags: calculus

> Consider the function $f(x) =\sqrt{1 + \sin(x)}$. Derive the first
>   few terms in the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ around $x = 0$, up to and
>   including terms of order $x^2$. Give an explicit formula for the
>   remainder term. Note: you are *not* required to evaluate the integral
>   in this formula.

For the first part I get $\displaystyle 1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+\mathcal{O(x^3)}$

For the second part, I think I'm supposed to use the formula:

$\displaystyle R_k(x) = \int_a^x \frac{f^{(k+1)} (t)}{k!} (x - t)^k \, dt$

But I don't think I understand this formula enough to apply it. Should I let $a=0$ and $k=2$?

Comment: Why not use the Lagrange remainder: $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, $a=0, k=2$. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem.

Comment: @KittyL The question refers to "the integral", so I imagine they're expecting the form he mentions.

Comment: I see. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly right.

Your remainder term will be

$$R_2(x) = \int_0^x \frac{f^{(3)} (t)}{3!} (x - t)^3 \, dt$$

where you need to substitute the expression for $f^{(3)}(t)$. Your text might have some assumption on $f$ that you need to check to be sure that you can write the remainder in this integral form.